# Samza 1.1.0 - run-app.sh does not work during deployment of hello samza

Tags: amazon-emr, apache-samza

I am facing errors when I deploy the hello samza tutorial on yarn following the documentation. Particularly, I was getting errors when I run the run-app.sh script as mentioned.

I am currently using Samza 1.1.0 on AWS EMR (emr - 5.13.0, amazon 2.8.3, zookeeper 3.4.10) and I am trying to deploy hello samza using the documentation provided on samza (https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/latest/deployment/yarn.html). Firstly, I could not find bin/build-package.sh but I used bin/deploy.sh to build the maven package. Then, I tried running the following script run-app.sh

```
./deploy/samza/bin/run-app.sh --config-factory=org.apache.samza.config.factories.PropertiesConfigFactory --config-path ./deploy/samza/config/filter-example.properties
```

The documentation says that I should be able to deploy the job now but I get the following error which says

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.samza.runtime.ApplicationRunnerMain
```